# Proving a chain of well-formed formulas in metalogic

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have a set of assumptions $\Delta$ and can show that $\Delta \vdash A$, and then $A \vdash B$.

Are we then able to say $\Delta \vdash B$?  If so what lets us say this?

Comment: What does "*and then* $A \vdash B$" mean?  Are you trying to ask "If whenever $\Delta \vdash A$ it also holds $A \vdash B$, then are we able to say..." or are you asking "If $\Delta \vdash A$ and $A \vdash B$, then are we able to say..." ?

Comment: @DanielV I don't see the difference between your two examples?

Comment: Do see the difference between "If, whenever it is Tuesday it is raining, then...." vs "If it is Tuesday and it is raining, then...." ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how that would change the above examples/interpretations. So I guess I'll just say "both/either"

Comment: It depends on you mean by "and then".  For example, the follow is true of any sound arithmetic logic:

> Whenever $0 = 0 \vdash 1 = 2$ then $1 = 2 \vdash 3 = 4$

because it never holds that $0=0 \vdash 1=2$.  However, it is not the case that $0 = 0 \vdash 3 = 4$.

On the other hand, if you mean "both" then the claim holds.

Comment: $\Delta \vdash A$ is a finite *sequence* of formulas $<\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n>$ where $\varphi_n=A$. Thus, continue the list with $A \vdash B$ that, in turn is a sequence ending with $B$. The  two concatenated sequences are a new sequence corresponding to $\Delta \vdash B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes. You can just concatenate the first proof and the second proof and it will yield the third proof.

Precise details of how you glue them together to get another well formed proof will depend on the deductive system. (But e.g. in a Hilbert-style system it is as simple as appending the lines of the second proof to the end of the first.)

Comment: Like in a Hilbert system if we have a set of assumptions $\Delta$ and some wffs $A$ and $B$ where $\Delta, A \vdash B$ then axioms like $B \to (A \to B)$ let us, with modus ponens, infer that $A \to B$, and then we're somehow able to jump straight to $\Delta \vdash A \to B$

Comment: No, where did the $A$ left of the turnstile come from / go? If we have $\Delta, A\vdash B$ then using the axiom $B\to A\to B$ and MP gives $\Delta, A\vdash A\to B.$ We are able to jump to there by adding a couple of lines to the proof. Alternatively, that axiom is equivalent to having $B\vdash A\to B,$ to match the form of your question more precisely.

Comment: (I'm referencing the deduction theorem here which says $\Delta, A \vdash B \implies \Delta \vdash A \to B$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem )

Comment: Sure, but I don’t see what that has to do with your question. The deduction theorem is stronger than what this argument can give you.

Comment: It's directly related from the theorem so I'm not sure what you mean (see first comment)

Comment: I did see your first comment. I am saying the reasoning in my answer and your comment only allow you to conclude $\Delta, A\vdash A\to B,$ not the stronger $\Delta\vdash A\to B.$ The deduction theorem is more work.

Comment: I'm asking how you jump over to $\Delta \vdash A \to B$ because I don't see how you get there

Comment: this is what I’m saying... the deduction theorem cannot be obtained from this line of reasoning (and thus doesn’t have much of a connection to your question). You need to actually consult a proof of  the deduction theorem.

Comment: I did, here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Deduction_Theorem They just jump over

Comment: I shouldn’t say that... this reasoning may well be used in a proof of the deduction theorem, but it is not sufficient.

Comment: Ok... well if you have a question about the proof, you should ask it. The question you asked has the answer I gave. The way to get the deduction theorem is not to magically erase the $A$ but to follow the whole proof, which uses both axiom 1 and 2.

Comment: Didn’t see that you said they jump over. I’m not sure where you’re saying they do but it’s probably where they make a valid use the induction hypothesis

Comment: My question applies to several steps they use all over the place in that proof, as well as their final jumps to $U \vdash$ in general

Comment: I have a answered the question you asked with a straightforward “yes”. I can’t tell if you’re trying to justify your claim that this question (i.e. the initial question) has something to do with the proof of the deduction theorem or saying that there are multiple jumps you don’t understand in the proof.

Comment: Yes, I am saying it has something to do with the proof of the deduction -- I didn't understand why we were able to say that if we've proven some new thing we can attach it to the original source rather than the thing we derived it from directly. I don't know what "lets us" do this or if it's all informal reasoning / metalogic.

Comment: Didn't understand or don't? A proof in a Hilbert system is a list of formulas that obeys certain rules. When we construct one proof from others it is metalogical reasoning about the proofs. The proof that establishes $\Delta \vdash A$ can be concatenated with the one that establishes $A\vdash B$ to get a valid proof of $B$ from $\Delta$. This is a metalogical assertion established by metalogical reasoning. The more complicated inductive argument that a proof of  $A\to B$ from $\Delta$ exists whenever a proof of $B$ from $\Delta, A$ exists is also a metalogical argument.

Comment: Yes but that's not quite what I'm asking

Comment: I asked a more detailed question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920880/trouble-proving-the-deduction-theorem

Comment: I'll let that question stand on its own and let someone else take a whack at it rather than hopping over and continuing, but I answered it in the comments here. We have only shown the weaker statement. There's a reason why the argument for the deduction theorem is a more complicated induction on the proof length. You don't just 'get rid of' the A on the LHS, you need a whole new argument.

Comment: It's like you've said "I've proven $\pi$ is irrational, which it clearly is if $\pi$ is transcendental. Is this a proof that $\pi$ is transcendental? nd if not,  how do I take care of this little issue that I haven't shown it isn't the solution of a polynomial eqn with integer coefficients?"

Comment: I don't really know what you're saying. I feel like we're talking about different things / talking past each other. Look at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Deduction_Theorem -- they basically jump straight to $U \vdash$ in most of their arguments.

Comment: No they don't. They *get* there, justifying everything. (Thus they use a more complicated argument than you think they're using.) Pick one, I'll explain it.

Comment: Will go in order then: $n = 1$ case, where $B \in U$. They say "obviously $U \vdash B$" with no explanation. Then they say by axiom 1, $U \vdash B \to (A \to B)$ with no explanation as to why we can say this is coming from $U$.

Comment: If $B\in U,$ then we can prove $B$ from $U$ with a one line proof: $B.$ We're done. (This is way they say it's obvious that $U\vdash B.$) If something is an axiom then it can be proven from $U$ in one line as well: just write down the axiom. (It doesn't matter that you didn't need to use anything in $U$). As you said in your other question, a line in a proof is either an 1. axiom, 2.an assumption from $U$, or 3. follows from previous lines via MP.  Here we used 1 and 2 respectively to make one-line proofs from $U$ of $B\to (A\to B)$ and of $B.$

Comment: What lets us say that if $B \in U$ then $U \vdash B$? Is this just informal reasoning?

Comment: "(It doesn't matter that you didn't need to use anything in U)" -- according to what? What lets us do this?

Comment: And when we proved $A \to B$ with modus ponens what lets us say it was derived from $U$? (it was derived from $B$ and $B \to (A \to B)$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83300/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-user525966).